# Kivy Label background color from hex

Tags: kivy

Is it possible to set `Label` background color as hex value similar to below 
exaples?

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

#:set gray_dark hex('#c2c2c2')

<Label@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    bcolor: gray_dark
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

The only way that works for me is when I set `bcolor:` to rgba value. Would be fine even when I could define the color as rgba but do it once at the top as below:

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

#:set gray_dark (0.752, 0.745, 0.745, 1)

<Label@Label>
    background_normal: ''        
    bcolor: gray_dark
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Both codes throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Which is quite obvious as hex is not a list.

Comment: Just referencing `gray_dark` works for me. What version of `kivy` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Root Cause

The following error was encountered because when the app starts, the attribute, `bcolor` has a value of `None`.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

## Solution

Add `if...else` statement to check for `None` value.

### Snippets

```
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)  if self.bcolor is None else self.bcolor
```

## Note

The following example illustrates assigning `hex()` directly to `rgba`.

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: hex('#c2c2c2')
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
```

## Example

### main1.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import sp kivy.metrics.sp

#:set gray_dark hex('#c2c2c2')

<Label@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    bcolor: gray_dark
    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    text: "set gray_dark hex('#c2c2c2')"
    font_size: sp(30)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)  if self.bcolor is None else self.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

Label:

"""))
```

## Output

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]